# Printing with DeviceHub - Identifying Printer Access groups printers

Tags: acumatica

Based on a research of Acumatica's page Print Statements (AR503500), I was able to identify the following key tables:

- **RelationGroup:** Printer Access Groups where the users are assigned
- **SMPrinter:** printers associated to the aforementioned groups
- **Field Users.GroupMask:** the link between the user and the group

[SQL Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvQuj.jpg)

The relation between RelationGroup and SMPrinter is pretty straightforward via the GroupMask column.

However because of the potential use of the same user in multiple groups, the relation between Users.GroupMask and the table RelationGroup is a bit more complicated.

Translating the hexadecimal values from the group mask columns, we can see that each group is represented in a separate bit position:

```
0x40000000 -- 0100 0000
0x08000000 -- 0000 1000
0x10000000 -- 0001 0000
0x04000000 -- 0000 0100
```

In our case, the admin user belongs to the following groups: Cash Account Access, Fixed Asset Account Branch Access, Limit Access to Employees, Test

So it is identified with this binary value: 01011100 which corresponds to the 0x5C00 result from the query previously shown for the users table.

Is there an Acumatica method that could be used to obtain this result in a more direct way? Example: we enter the user and obtain all the Printer access groups he/she belongs to?

The closest method that I identified that could provide this information is the SearchPrinter() method, however, it only returns the default printer for either the User, the notification or the branch, but does not return the list of printers associated to the logged on user.

Comment: You won't be able to do simple SQL Joins to achieve that. Bitwise operations would be needed. Can you clarify why you need to get to this via SQL? Acumatica will take care of filtering the data so that a user can only see the data he has access too, so you almost never need to worry about that field yourself.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel thanks for your answer, the SQL reference was for explanation purposes only. I agree, we should handle everything within Acumatica. I am looking for a way to obtain the Printer access groups a user belongs to. We have separate printers (one for labels and for instructions) and we need to identify the corresponding printer based on these groups.

Comment: You might find this article useful - http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/08/restriction-groups-architecture.html